# Python PyAutoGUI (automatic mouse macro)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to display the (x.y) coordinates of the mouse found using "pyautogui.position()" on the window. What command should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the x,y mouse positions, you can use `.position()` like so:

```py
print(pyautogui.position())
```

It will output something like `(346, 653)` (the numbers will be different, and this is just an example) where the first value is the x coordinate of the cursor, and the second value being the y coordinate.